# Delete others' comments on my own post

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, comments

If you use social media, you may know that all comments others posted on your **own** posts can be deleted by **you** if you see that it is unnecessary.

I know TeX.SE, or SE in general, is not a social media site, but its format is somewhat the same as social media (there are posts, there are comments, there are up/down-votes (like "Like"/"Dislike"), there is even chat). So **I think it is good if we can delete comments on my own post**.

Some of the comments recently posted on my posts are very looooong and not useful at all. That is why I want this feature.

Comment: Such a feature request needs to be posted at https://meta.stackexchange.com/ as we on TeX.SE do not have a direct influence on the SE feature set. Please check if there is already one. I guess you will not have much success with it, though.

Comment: One way to handle such comments is to flag them as "no longer needed" so a moderator can delete it for you.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thank you very much!

Comment: I see the analogy, but remember that the StackOverflow rules are that by posting content your are making it available under an open license: you are 'giving up control' to some extent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is already solved.

Comment: @JouleV: If you want to conclude the question, just accept one of the answers. I posted my comment as one now. I tagged the question also as "status-bydesign" so the feature-request is concluded as well.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, the discussion on Meta SE: [Delete others' comments on my own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322863) (status declined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not part of the stackexchange feature set. New features can only be requeseted on the primary meta site https://meta.stackexchange.com/. Feel free to post your request there.

If you want to have certain comments under your post removed, you can flag them for moderator attention. A moderator can then delete them. The neutral way is to flag them as "no longer needed", while there are other flags if needed.

Comment: While there's nothing wrong posting a feature request on per-site meta since SE staffs also monitor them, I don't think this idea will go well if posted on Meta SE since the feature is very open for being abused and censoring (e.g. "I don't like you, so I delete your comments).

Answer (score 3):

It is true that tex.stackexchange looks a lot like a social network of friends who greet each other, vote for each other (and point it out), ask for relevant comments to be deleted because the person who made the comment is not a friend or a buddy.

However, stackexchange is not a network of friends. It is a place of mutual support open to all and everyone must accept that others give their opinions and criticism.

By allowing everyone to delete unpleasant comments, this place then becomes a real facebook, which it tends to become more and more, I regret it.

So I find this idea bad because it goes against the very philosophy of sharing and mutual aid of stackexchange.